# profiler for showing render statistics for web page?

Tags: javascript, profiler, html

I'm using a contrib drupal module that hooks into a form. Its presence appears to cause the jquery to render unreasonably slowly, but I'm not entirely sure about that.. I want to do some advanced troubleshooting on it, and I'm looking for a tool like xdebug that will give me an output file that I can view with KCacheGrind.

I've looked at Venkman and Firebug, but I don't want a debugging environment; I'm not at that point yet. I want to see a profile of the page load so I can see where the majority of the time was spent so I can identify where the problem is.

**Edit:** I'm actually not looking for a profile of the page load, as several folks have pointed out, but actually a profile of the javascript executed on a particular event. Firebug's debugger can grab the execution and step me into the code, but it just puts me at one point in the big ol' script. I think the slowdown involves loops and iterations, so I want to see a profile of the execution path.

Actually I think I should post this as a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firebug, click the "Net" tab.  It lists every element it requests from the server, and detailed connection and load information (on hover) with a nice graphic display without hover.

### Update

In addition, if actual page load isn't the issue, and you are indeed trying to profile Javascript, the Firebug "Console" tab probably has what you need.

Click "Profile" and then reload the page.  Click "Profile" again to see a list of everything the javascript did with duration and timing information.  This should show you what is taking the longest.

Comment: That won't help, he is suffering from a Javascript performance issue, not a network issue.

Comment: I assumed that, but this quote "I want to see a profile of the page load so I can see where the majority of the time was spent" makes me think it's hanging on load, which probably would be shown by the Firebug Net tab, even if it doesn't directly address the Javascript.  At least it would indicate at which step a long lag is happening, based on the duration and start and end times of loads.

Comment: @rocketerest, after rereading the question, you might be right.  It is somewhat ambiguous, but the tools mentioned xdebug and KCacheGrind are code profilers.

Answer (score 0):

The chrome developer tools has a javascript profiler, that will profile all of the function calls on your page.  The timeline feature (might only be in beta/dev versions) will show how much time the browser spends on various operations (layout and rendering for example) operations.

I believe that firebug also has a JS profiler.

Answer (score 0):

There is a profiler in firebug in the console tab. Click once to  start and second to stop the profiler. Chrome has also a profiler press ⌘⌥j. There is also a good profiling tool for internet explorer: [dynaTrace ajax editon](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/).

Btw. most of the time jquery is slow depends on wrong use of the selector engine.